# Change my postgresql password in OSX?

Tags: postgresql, osx-lion

I am trying to set my local postgresql so it does not have a password. I understand that this has to be done in the `pg_hba.conf` file and to acceess that file I have to be a `postgres` user. But to be a `postgres` user, I have to login with `su postgres` and enter the password that I don't have.

Any solution to this (I am on OSX)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing several different concepts about the security model.

There is a `postgres` operating system user, which the PostgreSQL server runs as in order to isolate its data files and to limit damage in case of a security breach or application bug. PostgreSQL won't run as `root` for security. This user doesn't generally have a password, but you can change to it via the root account using `sudo` - you can `sudo` to this user with something like `sudo -i -u postgres`.

There is also a `postgres` *database*  user, the default database superuser. This user doesn't generally have a password by default, but `pg_hba.conf` allows the `postgres` operating system user to connect as the `postgres` PostgreSQL user using `peer` authentication.

If you want you can change the configuration so that you use a password for the `postgres` database user, so you can `psql -U postgres` from any system user account:

- `ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'blahblah';`
- Edit `pg_hba.conf` ("hba" is "host-based authentication") to use `md5` authentication for `local` and `host` connections.
- Re-start or re-load PostgreSQL

Similarly, if you want to allow any system user to connect as any database user without a password, you must modify `pg_hba.conf` and set `trust` as the authentication mode for `local` and `host` connection types. Please only use `trust` authentication for testing.

To learn more, see [the client authentication chapter in the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But when I do the `psql -U postgres` command, I am asked for a password...what can this be? (The only thing I really want is to get access to the `pg_hba.conf` file to alter it.)

Comment: @allegutta That suggests your `pg_hba.conf` is set to `md5` authentication for `local` users. If you want to disable that you can set it to `trust`. To edit the file you'll need to become the `postgres` *system* user using `sudo -u postgres -i`. If your system user account has a password (to unlock your screen etc) it'll prompt you for that one. You don't edit `pg_hba.conf` via `psql`, but using operating system tools directly.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. I managed to alter my `pg_hba.conf` file! :)